# Deploy an CF application to a Windows Mobile Device (with config file)

Tags: .net, compact-framework, setup-project, setup-deployment, .net-cf-3.5

I have an application, built on CF3.5 and I’m trying to work out how to deploy this to the device.  I’ve created a deployment project, and that deploys the software fine.

However, the project has an app.config file to hold some running parameters.

What I need to be able to do is to produce the CAB file, and allow the config to be changed before it is synced to the device (changing it once it’s on the device is not viable).  The problem I have is that if I include this in the set-up project, then it will be included in the produced CAB file and end up in the application directory on the device.

I’m aware that the contents of the CAB file can be changed, but this is quite a cumbersome process.  It there a way to have the installation program just copy a file named app.config from the same directory as the CAB file to wherever the program is installed?  Alternatively, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I know Advanced Installer can create Windows Mobile installers. Perhaps it supports what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could create a custom [setup.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924308.aspx) for your CAB and modify the app.config with it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look into [Mortscript](http://www.sto-helit.de/index.php?module=page&entry=ms_overview). This is a scripting language that runs on windows mobile.

I have myself done some configuration of a custom application, however AFTER the installation. But you could also manipulate something first, then install the cap with the same script.